# Ayuda comprimir archivos y carpetas a zip dentro del mismo directorio de salida Java

Tags: java

Hola tengo un problema con este programa, me comprime los archivos en le mismo directorio como deseo, pero las carpetas no están bien comprimidas dentro del archivo de salida para las carpetas, me genera un archivo de salida incorrecto. será que alguien me pudiera decir donde es que me estoy equivocando. aquí les dejo el código. Gracias de ante mano

```
    package clases23flujoEntradaSalida;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ComprimirArchivosDentroDeCarpetaAZip {


    private static String directorioZip = "src" + File.separator + "clases23flujoEntradaSalida" + File.separator + "test zip" + File.separator;
    // ruta completa donde están los archivos a comprimir
    private static File carpetaComprimir = new File(directorioZip);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        comprimirArchivos(directorioZip, carpetaComprimir);
    }



    public static void comprimirArchivos(String directorioZip, File carpetaAComprimir) {



        // cadena que contiene la ruta donde están los archivos a comprimir

                File[] ficheros = carpetaComprimir.listFiles();

                // valida si existe el directorio
                if (carpetaComprimir.exists()) {
                    // lista los archivos que hay dentro del directorio

                    System.out.println("Número de ficheros encontrados: " + ficheros.length);

                    // ciclo para recorrer todos los archivos a comprimir
                    for (int i = 0; i < ficheros.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Nombre del fichero: " + ficheros[i].getName());
                        String extension="";
                        for (int j = 0; j < ficheros[i].getName().length(); j++) {
                            //obtiene la extensión del archivo
                            if (ficheros[i].getName().charAt(j)=='.') {
                                extension=ficheros[i].getName().substring(j, (int)ficheros[i].getName().length());
                                //System.out.println(extension);
                            }
                        }
                        try {
                            // crea un buffer temporal para ir poniendo los archivos a comprimir
                            ZipOutputStream zous = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directorioZip + ficheros[i].getName().replace(extension, ".zip")));

                            //nombre con el que se va guardar el archivo dentro del zip
                            ZipEntry entrada = new ZipEntry(ficheros[i].getName());
                            zous.putNextEntry(entrada);

                                //System.out.println("Nombre del Archivo: " + entrada.getName());





                                if(ficheros[i].isDirectory()) {
                                    System.out.println("Directorio");
                                    //Aqui es donde hay que arreglar el problema

                                    zous =  new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directorioZip + ficheros[i].getName() + ".zip"));






                                    //nombre con el que se va guardar el archivo dentro del zip
                                    entrada = new ZipEntry(ficheros[i].getName());
                                    zous.putNextEntry(entrada);




                                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(entrada.getName());
                                    int leer;
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                    while (0 < (leer = fis.read(buffer))) {
                                        zous.write(buffer, 0, leer);


                                    }

                                }else {

                                    System.out.println("Comprimiendo.....");
                                    //obtiene el archivo para irlo comprimiendo
                                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(directorioZip+entrada.getName());
                                    int leer;
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                    while (0 < (leer = fis.read(buffer))) {
                                        zous.write(buffer, 0, leer);
                                    }
                                    fis.close();
                                    zous.closeEntry();
                                zous.close();       

                                }

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }               
                    }
                    System.out.println("Directorio de salida: " + directorioZip);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No se encontró el directorio..");
                }



    }






    }
```

Si alguien me pudiera explicar donde estoy fallando se lo agradecería mucho, porque de verdad estoy peleando con esto hace unos días y no logro ver donde esta el problema.